# How is unmanaged memory allocated in system when instances are created?

Tags: c#, .net, memory-management, unmanaged-memory

How is unmanaged memory allocated in system when COM objects or any other unmanaged instances are created from C#?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The CLR creates a Runtime Callable Wrapper (RCW) for the COM objects you want to instantiate. This is a kind of interop proxy from .NET to the COM system. The COM object you create is therefore allocated and a reference to it created in the CLR, which puts it on the heap.

You must always implement `IDisposable` in the class that holds references to RCWs, because they are not automatically cleaned up (the wrappers are on the .NET heap, but the COM objects themselves are not). Calling `Dispose()` on the wrapper releases the COM objects. Not implementing `IDisposable` therefore causes memory leaks.

Comment: It's important to clarify that when multiple managed references to a single RCW instance is shared, it's reference count (nothing to do with the COM object's RC) is still ONE (only increased if live in more than one AppDomain). I.e., trying to do a ReleaseComObject on it will kill the RCW for ANYONE else using it as well (it is not reference counted in the traditional sense, inside an AppDomain), like a lot of people seem to think. Also, an RCW WILL be garbage collected eventually, if noone references it, but it is non-deterministic like any GC. See http://dotnetdebug.net/category/com-interop/

Comment: Main(0
{

ComObject1 comObj1 = new ComObject1();

comObj1.SomeMethod(10);


Marshal.ReleaseComObject(comObj1);

}

please explain me how memory is allocated in the above examples for ComObject1

Comment: @Srinivas (Unmanaged) Memory is allocated for the COM object. (Managed) Memory is then allocated for an RCW. The RCW refcount is 1 no matter how many unmanaged OR managed references to it you have. ReleaseComObject forces the RCW refcount to 0. The COM object MAY not be deallocated at this point of someone else (outside the managed AppDomain) is holding a reference to it. If noone does, it is deallocated when its internal RC becomes 0. The managed RCW continues to exist, until it is garbage collected. The link I posted in the comment above describes the details. Also see http://goo.gl/eK1WN

Answer (score 0):

My guess is they result in a call to the OS to create their memory on the unmanaged heap.  The CLR would obviously have nothing to do with them as they are unmanaged.